# Solve Catastrophic Backtracking in my regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to detect names (French names) that can be in the following formats

`CHARLES`

`CHARLES-ANTOINE`

`D'URENBURRY`

`CHARLES--ANTOINE`

`CHARLES ANTOINE`

And for that I have the following regex

```
/^([A-Z]+(([-]{0,2}|[']|[ ])?[A-Z]+))+$/
```

Which works, but GitHub's code scanner shows this error

```
This part of the regular expression may cause exponential backtracking on strings containing many repetitions of 'AA'.
```

I understand the error, however, I'm not sure how to solve it.

My question is: how to solve it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-write the pattern like

```
^[A-Z]+(?:(?:-{1,2}|[' ])[A-Z]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T5st43/1). Now, each subsequent pattern will match different string, at different locations inside the string.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z]+` - one or more uppercase ASCII letters
- `(?:(?:-{1,2}|[' ])[A-Z]+)*` - zero or more repetions of:

  - `(?:-{1,2}|[' ])` - a non-capturing group matching one or two hyphens, a space or apostrophe
  - `[A-Z]+` - one or more uppercase ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.